# Programmatically pluralize type name in Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a fairly simple issue, but I couldn't find a solution googling it.
I'm writing a library with Java/Spring and I need to be able to convert the names of types in the usual Java Bean ways: uncapitalized and (sometimes) plural.

*Example*: for a class called **NorseDeity** I must be able to get the String "**norseDeity**" and "**norseDeities**".

*Is there any Spring or Apache Commons method to perform such a conversion?*

I know Spring itself does it (because it automagically names different properties correctly), but I can't find how to reproduce it.

Comment: Uncapitalizing a word is pretty trivial in Java, but deriving the plural form is pretty tricky stuff. [Evo Inflector](https://github.com/atteo/evo-inflector) looks very promising, and even claims that it's used by Spring.

Comment: The best way to do this is not to do it at all.  Even the library suggested by E-Riz has limited accuracy.  To be truly accurate would require linguistic context.  I would consider a static Map of class names to plural names.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I do not need linguistic accuracy, I just need to be able to reproduce what Spring Data already does automatically, and I don't know beforehand the names I'm going to convert

Comment: What happened to the accepted answer? Evo Inflector was exactly what I was looking for